# CMD + M does not show up debuggger menu (I have tried all options for the last 5 hours)

Tags: react-native

I have been struggling for past few hours to open debugger menu on android emulator. I have looked up all the questions on SO and tried all the options, but as soon as I press on command, the pinch option with two green circles show up. There is no option to disable this in android emulator. Did any of you face issue? Any help please?[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrhdI.png)

Comment: This is what happens on all emulators on my Mac. I have created new emulators too
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrhdI.png

Comment: For me the pinch option does show up but as soon as I press M it opens the debugger. You don't actually need to disable the pinch gesture for the debugger to show

Comment: @Danyal it’s not going away for me, I have been try all sorts of things.. even trying to open the debugger menu programmatically, the menu just doesn’t show up. I even deleted and installed latest android studio too!! It’s been almost 10 hours :(